# php REQUEST_URI multi language not showing

Tags: php, url, utf-8, character-encoding

**Example 1**

> http://localhost/example.com/en/softwares/operating-system/

When I `echo $myvalue = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` it prints

> /example.com/en/softwares/operating-system/

**Exampe 2**

> [http://localhost/example.com/zh/软件/操作系统/](http://localhost/example.com/zh/%E8%BD%AF%E4%BB%B6/%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E7%B3%BB%E7%BB%9F/)

When I `echo $myvalue = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` it prints

> /example.com/zh/%E8%BD%AF%E4%BB%B6/%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E7%B3%BB%E7%BB%9F/

I don't know why? Some languages display properly. But, few languages (chinese, russian, bulgarian) didn't show properly. In my header I set

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and I also updated php file into Unicode through dreamweaver -> modify -> page properties

I tried this `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` is my .htaccess file. It didn't work.

Also tried this in my php file `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` It also didn't work.

`$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` only not showing the languages properly. Otherwise in my webpages all languages are shown properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is always url-encoded. Just do

```
$decoded = rawurldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```